# Change reexec value from 128 in full node sync

Tags: go-ethereum, state-trie, full-node, archive-node

I need to retain not only the most recent 128 block in **full mode** but e.g. last 1000 blocks for my purposes. The greater the value of reexec the longer the tracing will take because more blocks have to be re-executed to regenerate the target state. So I want to make it much faster by saving more latest blocks. Also I have no need to use archive mode cause it takes a lot of space. To summer up, my goal is to improve geth source code.

I've changed only TriesInMemory (core/blockchain.go) and defaultTraceReexec (eth/tracers/api.go) vars but it's not enough I guess

Comment: how do you know it is not enough? what is your proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to wait more time. So, now everything works fine after just changing these two params TriesInMemory and defaultTraceReexec. Maybe this will help someone in the future